# How to integrate Power BI in ASP.NET applications to generate Power BI reports?

Tags: asp.net, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and I need to generate Power BI reports from the ASP.NET application.

How can we integrate Power BI in .NET applications in order to generate Power BI reports?
I tried Power BI desktop version and created reports.
How can Power BI reports be generated through .NET applications?

Comment: did u find the answer for that ?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend looking into Power BI embedded documentation. The resource contains several tutorials on how to embed a Power BI report in your asp.net web app using azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/powerbi-embedded?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: The above link is broken. Here is another link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/powerbi-embedded?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate in your asp.net application, by the way you can embed this in every cross platform whether it's asp, PHP, Python etc etc, so here is solution,

1. Publish your dashboard to your PowerBI Online.
2. Goto your Online PowerBI and view your report then

   2.1. Goto File Tab.

   2.2. Click Publish On web.

   2.3. Copy Embedded code/ iframe and paste iframe code in your application.

Comment: How should we integrate PBI dashboard in WebForms? As dashboard doesn't have EmbbedCode.

Answer (score -2):

No dear its not possible to create power bi reports from .Net platform however you can integrate power Bi reports to your .Net Application via iframe after publish online, you can find this procedure here, i  just recently post answer here,

[How to integrate PowerBI in ASP.NET applications to generate PowerBI reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674846/how-to-integrate-powerbi-in-asp-net-applications-to-generate-powerbi-reports/52918330#52918330)

Comment: It's not an answer. Please rephrase it if you can.